# Beego httplib.get filter JSON

Tags: json, go, beego

I'm new in Golang, and have a problem. I use package `github.com/astaxie/beego/httplib`, try to get info from API

```
res := httplib.Get("example.com")

type SomeStruct struct {
   Type string
   Id string
   // ...
}

var itemStruct SomeStruct

err := res.ToJSON(&itemStruct)
```

Problem: in API response Id field might be string or number (depending on Type field), thats why I get error `json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string`. I think, I must filter response before ToJSON method. Or I must create struct with only field Type, get data from API, filter by Type. But in this case how can I get other fields? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to make `Type` of type `interface{}`?

Casting in go is quite clean so you could then iterate and cast when you are using the type

```
for _, s := ss {
    switch v := s.Type.(type) {
    case string:
        // Do something
    cast int:
        // Do something else
    default:
        // Handle unexpected type gracefully.
    }
}
```